# Saving/Retrieving image from sql server to express api into react app

Tags: javascript, sql-server, reactjs, t-sql, sql-server-2014

My table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t_picures(
  picureId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  extension NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  picture VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_pictureId PRIMARY KEY (pictureId)
);
```

I'm able to save an image into my SQL Server using the following SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t_picture
VALUES (N'Smile.png', N'.png',
    (
        SELECT  *  
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\{Path to my image}\Smile.png',SINGLE_BLOB) AS picture
    )
)
```

When I `SELECT picture FROM dbo.t_pictures WHERE name='Smile.png'` the resulting column yields a resulting column that looks something like: `0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200006400640000FFDB0043...` (It goes on for MUCH longer).  I think that this is a long array of bytes.

I then send it through my express api and `console.log(this.state.data.picture)` the results on the client side of my react app.  The picture column looks like this when it is console.logged in my react app: `{type: "Buffer", data: Array(14598)}`

I attempted to create an image by using `<img src={this.state.data.picture} />` but the image appears as broken.

I've read in a few places that you can display this by converting the buffer array into a base64 string, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I'm also not sure if I should do that in T-SQL when I'm first retrieving the data, or if I should convert it in javscript when I receive it on the client side.

How can I display the image using the value from `{type: "Buffer", data: Array(14598)}`?  Also, is there a better approach to storing/retrieving images from sql server?

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display the image by casting the binary value to a base64 string when retrieving the data from the db by using the following query:

```
cast('' as xml).value(
  'xs:base64Binary(sql:column("table.column"))', 'varchar(max)'
)
```

table is your table name, column is your column name

I then displayed the image by using a data URI like so:

```
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.data.picture}`} />
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into the same issue!